# Modulus operator not behaving as expected in javascript?

Tags: javascript, modulus

I have the following:

```
-1 mod 5
```

I expect to get `4`.

However in JS (`-1 % 5`), I'm getting `-1`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: By what logic would you expect to get 4?

Comment: @torazaburo google logic: https://www.google.com/search?q=-1+mod+5&rlz=1C1CHZL_enUS749US749&oq=-1+mod+5&aqs=chrome.0.69i59.2215j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: The number -1 is equal to 4 (modulo 5).

Comment: @Pointy I must not understand basic math.  The fact remains that JS results != google arithmetic results.

Comment: As the wiki article linked from the duplicate states programming languages vary in how negatives are treated https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: You can always just add 5 if the result is negative. Highly recommend Underwood Dudley's classic [*Elementary Number Theory*](https://www.amazon.com/Elementary-Number-Theory-Second-Mathematics/dp/048646931X)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mod is the leftover when you divide the number by the divider.

In Math `-1%5 = -1` so Js is working as expected.

You are not doing anything wrong. If you want to get a positive number (the difference) add the divider number to the result.

```
var result = (-1 % 5) + 5;
```

It doesn't matter where you add the number before the module or after. Its a pure math.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=-1+mod+5&rlz=1C1CHZL_enUS749US749&oq=-1+mod+5&aqs=chrome.0.69i59.2215j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8